# How to properly parse and type graphql results?

Tags: json, typescript, graphql

Q: How do I parse and type a server response in a generic way when one of the parent keys in the response will constantly change?

As a preface: I'm still new to TS and parsing server responses - so maybe this is obvious - but after a day I've not found a good solution.

Background: I'm using Typescript and AWS Amplify. I have a graphql mutation called CreateGroup. It requires input of a code-generated type CreateGroupInput defined as such:

```
export type CreateGroupInput = {
  id?: string | null,
  name: string,
  createdAt?: string | null,
  updatedAt?: string | null,
};

//I'm using this as input to create a new db entry
const groupInfo: CreateGroupInput = {
  name: "new group",
  createdAt: time,
  updatedAt: time
};
```

I want to parse and type the result of the mutation so that I can access the id that gets created during the mutation process. IDEALLY this is what I would like to do:

```
const data = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.createGroup, {input: groupInfo}) as CreateGroupInput;
```

and have the data variable be of type CreateGroupInput with the server response all in the correct place. However the result I get back doesn't parse nicely because the structure is a bit different:

```
{
    "data": {
        "createGroup": {
            "id": "1d720f68-56bd-46a9-82ef-e060a5b07177",
            "name": "new group",
            "createdAt": "1580278766358",
            "updatedAt": "1580278766358"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing different combinations of JSON.Parse and JSON.stringify - but none of them work and honestly it feels like I am doing something really wrong. This function will eventually handle many different mutations - and I expect the name "createGroup" in the response to change for each of these - so I can't just parse "result.data.createGroup" either.

Which leads me to posting this question. How do I parse and type the server response in a generic way when the key "createGroup" in the response will constantly change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the results can ALSO be accessed by a key (in retrospect - this should have been obvious) - which allows me to use variables.

I added an extra input to the function "queryName" and then accessed the data using

`result.data[queryName]`

it's not IDEAL - but way better than the alternatives.